# Trying to use a VB Script in an SSIS package to get the Server name from a connection

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing an SSIS package that uses VB Scripts to send several confirmation emails.  One of the confirmation emails needs to have the name of the server from one of the connection managers.  I have a script doing the following:

```
Public Sub Main()

    '------------- Set Vriables
    Dim htmlMessageTo As String = _
      Dts.Variables("Email_To").Value.ToString
    Dim htmlMessageCC As String = _
      Dts.Variables("Email_CC").Value.ToString
    Dim htmlMessageFrom As String = _
      Dts.Variables("Email_From").Value.ToString

    Dim ServerAConnectionString As String = _
          DirectCast(Dts.Connections("ServerA").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), String)
    Dim smtpConnectionString As String = _
          DirectCast(Dts.Connections("Mail1").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), String)
    Dim smtpServerStr As String = _
      smtpConnectionString.Split(New Char() {"="c, ";"c})(1)

    Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient(smtpServerStr)

    Dim myMail As New MailMessage
    With myMail
        .From = New MailAddress(htmlMessageFrom)
        .To.Add(htmlMessageTo)
        If Len(htmlMessageCC) > 0 Then
            .CC.Add(htmlMessageCC)
        End If
        .IsBodyHtml = True
        .Subject = "The process failed for server " & ServerAConnectionString 
        .Body = "The process failed for server " & ServerAConnectionString 
    End With

    smtpServer.Send(myMail)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Where I'm trying to get just the server name of ServerA.  And the connection manager Mail1 is the SMTP server I'm using.  Everything is working fine for my other strings but this particular one gives me an error.  I believe I can get the connection string but don't know enough VB to parse it.  I'm hoping there is a way to get into the connection object and view the server name property, I just haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ADO.NET connections:

```
    Dim dbConn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = Dts.Connections("ServerA").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction)
    Dim dbServer As String = dbConn.DataSource
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(-1, "", dbServer, String.Empty, -1, False)
```

It yields the following in the log:

```
 [] Information: ServerName\InstanceName
```

OleDB connections are a bit trickier -- to access the same thing in a vb script, add a reference to the .NET assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, then use the following:

```
    Dim connectionManager As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("oleDBConnection")
    Dim cmParam As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100
    cmParam = CType(connectionManager.InnerObject, Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100)
    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = CType(cmParam.GetConnectionForSchema(), OleDb.OleDbConnection)
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(-1, "", conn.DataSource, String.Empty, -1, False)
```

Tested and verified reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/08/22/accessing-oledb-connection-managers-in-a-script.aspx

Comment: Ok, this may be a stupid question but can I set the `Dts.Events.FireInformation` function equal to a string or does it just put the value into a log somewhere?

Comment: yeah you don't need that -- it's just to output the value to a log, used for debugging.  `dbServer` is the string in my example that stores the server name.

Comment: Ahh, so dbServer contains `ServerName\InstanceName`.  Awesome, thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error on SqlConnection.  It's saying it doesn't exist.  Is there something I need to include to make it work?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain.  I'm now getting this error: Error: 0x1 at Email for Correct Counts Push 1: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Comment: ServerA is an OLE DB connection.